# How can i destucture a javascript object containing other objects within it

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a javascript object `k` from which i obtained `profile` via destructuring. The new object contains other objects within it (i.e including location, login ... and location contains other objects within it as well). The problem I am having now is printing out the gender (or any other property within the destructured object), it only works when I omit location in the line for destructuring the profile array. Please, I need assistance on how to resolve this properly.

```
let k = {
"results": [
{
  "gender": "male",
  "name": {
    "title": "mr",
    "first": "eliott",
    "last": "roussel"
  },
  "location": {
    "street": "9072 rue de l'abbé-migne",
    "city": "versailles",
    "state": "indre",
    "postcode": 83762,
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": "-4.2370",
      "longitude": "-139.6080"
    },
    "timezone": {
      "offset": "-8:00",
      "description": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
    }
  },
  "email": "eliott.roussel@example.com",
  "login": {
    "uuid": "3e2e9f7d-ca08-4c81-93b2-f42dd0bbb421",
    "username": "saddog976",
    "password": "chippy",
    "salt": "XPbHVGge",
    "md5": "70ab9b8e14cc0be868dc53995274f5b9",
    "sha1": "4cedb04743f2529ea2a801ec539f8f02731f659d",
    "sha256": "f2c6c1bcdcd0cc4de923501cd5bf87dbd1d948c95abc9f9b08a90b78ae7f5616"
  },
  "dob": {
    "date": "1960-08-08T00:53:25Z",
    "age": 58
  },
  "registered": {
    "date": "2004-07-15T15:57:51Z",
    "age": 14
  },
  "phone": "05-07-77-21-18",
  "cell": "06-64-48-62-07",
  "id": {
    "name": "INSEE",
    "value": "1NNaN32524474 85"
  },
  "picture": {
    "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg",
    "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/81.jpg",
    "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/81.jpg"
  },
  "nat": "FR"
}
],
"info": {
"seed": "d8ec8b34c6f6c368",
"results": 1,
"page": 1,
"version": "1.2"
 }
}
let l = k.results;
let profile = l[0];
const{gender, name, email, location, login, dob, registered, phone, cell, id, picture, nat} = profile;

alert(gender);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rename [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) property, because both are parts of the built in objects.

```js
var k = { results: [{ gender: "male", name: { title: "mr", first: "eliott", last: "roussel" }, location: { street: "9072 rue de l'abbé-migne", city: "versailles", state: "indre", postcode: 83762, coordinates: { latitude: "-4.2370", longitude: "-139.6080" }, timezone: { offset: "-8:00", description: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" } }, email: "eliott.roussel@example.com", login: { uuid: "3e2e9f7d-ca08-4c81-93b2-f42dd0bbb421", username: "saddog976", password: "chippy", salt: "XPbHVGge", md5: "70ab9b8e14cc0be868dc53995274f5b9", sha1: "4cedb04743f2529ea2a801ec539f8f02731f659d", sha256: "f2c6c1bcdcd0cc4de923501cd5bf87dbd1d948c95abc9f9b08a90b78ae7f5616" }, dob: { date: "1960-08-08T00:53:25Z", age: 58 }, registered: { date: "2004-07-15T15:57:51Z", age: 14 }, phone: "05-07-77-21-18", cell: "06-64-48-62-07", id: { name: "INSEE", value: "1NNaN32524474 85" }, picture: { large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg", medium: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/81.jpg", thumbnail: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/81.jpg" }, nat: "FR" }], info: { seed: "d8ec8b34c6f6c368", results: 1, page: 1, version: "1.2" } },
    { gender, name: name2, email, location: loc2, login, dob, registered, phone, cell, id, picture, nat } = k.results[0];

console.log(gender);
```

If you do not like to rename it, you could move the destructuring into an own function and use the variables as local variables.

```js
function process({ gender, name, email, location, login, dob, registered, phone, cell, id, picture, nat }) {
    return gender;
}

var k = { results: [{ gender: "male", name: { title: "mr", first: "eliott", last: "roussel" }, location: { street: "9072 rue de l'abbé-migne", city: "versailles", state: "indre", postcode: 83762, coordinates: { latitude: "-4.2370", longitude: "-139.6080" }, timezone: { offset: "-8:00", description: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" } }, email: "eliott.roussel@example.com", login: { uuid: "3e2e9f7d-ca08-4c81-93b2-f42dd0bbb421", username: "saddog976", password: "chippy", salt: "XPbHVGge", md5: "70ab9b8e14cc0be868dc53995274f5b9", sha1: "4cedb04743f2529ea2a801ec539f8f02731f659d", sha256: "f2c6c1bcdcd0cc4de923501cd5bf87dbd1d948c95abc9f9b08a90b78ae7f5616" }, dob: { date: "1960-08-08T00:53:25Z", age: 58 }, registered: { date: "2004-07-15T15:57:51Z", age: 14 }, phone: "05-07-77-21-18", cell: "06-64-48-62-07", id: { name: "INSEE", value: "1NNaN32524474 85" }, picture: { large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg", medium: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/81.jpg", thumbnail: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/81.jpg" }, nat: "FR" }], info: { seed: "d8ec8b34c6f6c368", results: 1, page: 1, version: "1.2" } },
    { results: { 0: profile } } = k;

console.log(process(profile));
```

Comment: Thank you. Renaming location worked, i just needed get that out of the way.

Comment: Oook, I thought getting location out of the way would solve the problem completely. Although, i am able to print out gender, i still get this error (---- You have not de-structured the 'profile' property from 'results' obtained from 'data' passed to 'displayUserPhotoAndName' function ------) when i try it on an online dev-tool-kit, and i don't want to use a function

Comment: and what does it mean?

Comment: What i understand by that error statement is that i have simply not touched the profile object in anyway (i.e i have not destructured the profile) .... i don't understand why its rejecting it, the code seems fine to me

Comment: maybe your data structure does not match.

Comment: I am extracting the original object (i.e the one it represented in my question as k) from an API using my browsers fetch function and converting the reponse to json (as in k above). Now, based on the structure of the response {an object containing other objects}, i created two statements that produced my userprofile object represented as k above ( here are the statements || const{results}=convertedjsonresponse;                                                           
const{[0]:profile}=results; ||) .. Please, How can i destructure this profile object. .may be with an arrow  function

Comment: the dev-kit just keeps popping out this error (---- You have not de-structured the 'profile' property from 'results' obtained from 'data' passed to 'displayUserPhotoAndName' function ------), even after i created this statement -- const{name:{title, first, last}, dob:{date,age}, phone, cell, location, picture:{large, medium, thumbnail}}= profile; -- to de-structure the profile property. I want to use the profile values as content for some DOM elements. Please, How can i get this to work correctly?

Comment: maybe this `{ results: { 0: profile } } = k;` works for you.